# Best way to design shopping cart domain model on C#?

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, architecture, domain-driven-design, shopping-cart

Google can`t help me. I find only this link: http://flylib.com/books/en/2.522.1.56/1/

So, once there is the question - why do we need divide Product and Item?

Answer (score 6):

`Product` is too complex to use it on your `Cart`. We can imagine that `Product` holds data about: Manufacturer, Quantities on Stock, Categories, etc. So the better way is to introduce an `Item` that will hold only reference to real Product (for example ProductId) and Quantity (and others informations you **need**).

Comment: Indeed; to expand on "Item" you could have PurchaseItem, CartItem, ProductReferenceItem - just food for thought.

Comment: I think, Item holds data about specific attributes as color, also about Manufacturer, Quantities, Supplier, and Product holds Categories, Name, Description

Comment: Funny fact that I had the same discussion about these terms with my colleagues so many times... and we actually got to the conclusion that "Item" in a cart can represent anything - from a voucher to a car. So we decided to move away from that abstraction and actually discuss products/articles, coupons, and promotions, but not items. 

If your domain treats items as a product then I need to question that one, as for retail that doesn't make sense; in the same pot, we decide to throw the "token", as that can represent any accessible way of identification and nothing concrete.

Answer (score 1):

Google cannot write code for you, it doesn't know you. I suggest you ask your users exactly what they want, and just do it. In my experience (almost 20 years of coding), I've found that reinventing the wheel almost always takes less time in the long term than trying to use an existing wheel to fit into different specifications. All projects are unique.

Of course, you can take inspiration from what you find, but don't expect it to match your specifications.

Comment: Thanks, but I have found no samples to take inspiration.